# Tungsten-replicator from MySQL to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, tungsten-replicator

When speaking of replicating data from MySQL to MongoDB,It seems that the tables in MySQL are almost the same as MongoDB's collections.However I want to take the MongoDB's  flexible schema into considerations to map a relation database into a database in MongoDB with different data schema.So How can I tell the Tungsten-replicator using a special applier to replicate the data?

For example:I have a MySQL database named A,with 10 tables,however when considering  MongoDB schema,I build a same database in MongoDB with 6 collections which map the models from MySQL database A.Now I want to replicate the data from MySQL to MongoDB,how can I do that?

Comment: Short answer is not with Tungsten replicator. This requires restructuring the entire transaction. And your schema design in mongo should be very different from that in a relational database (there's a lot more to it than nesting parent child relationships)

Comment: @symcbean yes! I want to  do some mapping from a relational database to mongodb databases and when i try to write the mysql database ,using tungsten-replicator ,I try to update the mongo database  with the thl based on mysql's bing-log.It's like a directed graph which help me figure out how should I write data in mongodb.

Comment: I also have a same question, searching for it now. 'll let you know if I found something

Comment: I also have a same question, searching for it now. 'll let you know if I found something